# How to convert Data Frame to a numeric matrix

Tags: r

I've a data frame with both characters and numbers and wish to convert it into a numeric matrix (As I need to make a heatmap out of it)

I've tried data.matrix and as.matrix functions but both are giving errors.

The data is currently in this form

```
season     team          average
1           a               45
1           b               32
1           c               15
2           a               43
2           b               45
2           c               34
3           a               45
```

and so on

And I wish to convert it into this

```
season       a           b             c
1            45          32            15
2            43          45            34
3            45          ...          ...
```

Sorry, If I've edited the question wrongly, I'm a bit new to both this platform and R

Answer (score 0):

You can re-shape your data frame with `spread`:

```
library(tidyr)

(df2 <- spread(df, key = team, value = average))

  season  a  b  c
1      1 45 32 15
2      2 43 45 34
3      3 45 NA NA
```

and then turn it into a matrix:

```
as.matrix(df2)
```